# Windows 10 Install Silently Ignore Incompatible Programs

Tags: windows, windows-10

I'm trying to upgrade some computers silently and remotely using the Windows 10 ISO.  I've already copied the ISO files to C:\Temp\ISO, so the setup.exe resides at C:\Temp\ISO\setup.exe.

I've tried running the program and running it silently with the parameters below:

```
C:\Temp\ISO\setup.exe /Auto Upgrade /Quiet /DynamicUpdate Disable /Compat IgnoreWarning /PostOOBE C:\Temp\clean.bat
```

However, when running the setup, it stops at the compatibility check because it says our antivirus is incompatible.   I know that it's compatible, so is there a way to ignore this?  The AV doesn't have a way to silently uninstall, so I would have to manually uninstall the antivirus each time before upgrading windows.

Basically I just need to be able to bypass the compatibility check or ignore it entirely.

Comment: At some point, Windows 10 will not install incompatible  software. I have seen this numerous times. Is your software too old?  Can it be upgraded?

Comment: @John its not old.  they just recently ended W7 support (its Trend Apex One).  As far as I know, it auto upgrades when they release patches for it.  Whenever a client is connected to the internet, it gets updated, so >99% of the clients are on the most recent version.

Comment: Can you make a script to uninstall the Trend antimalware, perform the update, and then reinstall it? If it will not install afterwards on a test unit, it makes the case for your administrators that the software is incompatible with then new version of Windows.

Comment: @cclloyd - It automatically upgrades the anti virus definitions, AV does not typically update itself, as in the actual program that is installed. That typically requires you to install an update. Out of interest what version do you have installed.

Comment: Do you have `DisableWUfBSafeguards` enabled or disabled?

Comment: You might also try `/DiagnosticPrompt enable` then updated your question.  This will hopefully indicated the reason the `/Compat` is being [ignored](https://www.asquaredozen.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/2018-07-18_8-37-24.jpg).  The output of the diagnostic prompt is really important.  You will have to enable it in order to view it at the appropriate step.

Comment: @Ramhound it was disabled, but setting that in the registry did not fix the issue either.  And running it with `/DiagnosticPrompt enable` did not change anything nor add any popups.

Comment: You have to use the keyboard shortcut to enabled the console during the installation process.  If I asked if something is enabled or disabled, please do not complicate the situation, by taking it upon yourself to change the setting.  I don't always explain my thought process but I almost always have a specific reason for asking for information.

Comment: Please would you take the time to mark some of the answers to your many questions as ✔ accepted. This is how you show the answers were useful to you. If people realise you never give the points you may find they're less inclined to help...